# displaying special messages (html/js) to mobile users

Tags: html

is there a special html/javascript code that I can use? So I basically have a non mobile optimised website. I want to show a simple one line message to users browsing my website using mobile devices. The message should only show to mobile users.

Your help is greatly appreciated! :)
Thanks

Comment: What's a mobile device?  My laptop is certainly mobile, but I bet your site works fine.  What about a tablet?  What about cell phones with higher resolution than my laptop?  This sort of thing is always a mess.  Build a site for folks to use on as many devices and resolutions as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into media queries for CSS. Basically, you can specify a max/min width, then make a class that is only visible on those widths.

For example:

```
.mobileView {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mobileView {
        /* CSS here */
    }
}
```

Please note that you can adjust the width as needed. Here is a quick [source](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to get you started.